# mySQL Quickly find rows linked to another row

Tags: mysql, database-design

For example if I have a `posts` table with `id` and a `likes` table width `id` `post_id` `user_id`, how can I set up the database to organize the `likes` table by `post_id` in order so queries are faster? I can't make the `post_id` the primary key because there are more than one likes for each post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, any given user can only like a given post once, so the `likes` table does not need and should not have an `id` column... Instead, define that table with `PRIMARY KEY (post_id,user_id)`.  The likes for a given post will be quickly retrievable using the leftmost column of the primary key for lookups and you then have automatic prevention of duplicate likes for the same post by the same user as a secondary benefit.